# No response from QnA service while integrating LUIS and QnA servie

Tags: node.js, azure, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I am trying to integrate LUIS and QnA service in a single bot. I used sample code available on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/samples/QnAMaker/QnAWithLUIS/app.js) to get a response for an intent. 
I tried with same code -

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var cognitiveservices = require('./node_modules/botbuilder-cognitiveservices/lib/botbuilder-cognitiveservices');
var botbuilder_azure = require("botbuilder-azure");

var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata
});

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var tableName = 'botdata';
var azureTableClient = new botbuilder_azure.AzureTableClient(tableName, process.env['AzureWebJobsStorage']);
var tableStorage = new botbuilder_azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, azureTableClient);


var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
//bot.set('storage', new builder.MemoryBotStorage());         // Register in-memory state storage
bot.set('storage', tableStorage);

var luisAppId = process.env.LuisAppId;
 var luisSubscriptionKey = process.env.LuisAPIKey;
 var luisApiHostName = process.env.LuisApiHostName || 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';
 var luisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisApiHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisSubscriptionKey;

var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(luisModelUrl);


var qnarecognizer = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
    authKey: process.env.QnAAuthKey,
    });

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer, qnarecognizer] });
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches('azureBotDevelopment', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        var answerEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'answer');
        session.send(answerEntity.entity);
    }
]);

intents.onDefault([
    function(session){
        session.send('Sorry!! No match!!');
    }
]);
```

When I run this bot in Web chat, for every question, it replies `Oops. Something went wrong and we need to start over.`
In online editor this gives the following error -

```
Error: QnA request returned a 404 code with body: [object Object]
    at Request._callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder-cognitiveservices\lib\QnAMakerRecognizer.js:98:37)
    at Request.self.callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this an entirely new project or are you trying to integrate LUIS/QnA into an already existing project?

Comment: I created a new bot with Azure and developed locally and redeployed it to azure.

Comment: Just double checking, but you have all of the various credentials for your bot, LUIS, and QnA in the bot's Configuration settings in Azure?

Comment: Yes, I have credentials for both LUIS and QnA in bot configuration settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organizing your code like below should work. I tested this using Web Chat and Emulator with positive results.

Essentially, bot.recognizer is acting like a middleware passing the returned LUIS intent into the bot and matching it to any triggers that have the same value assigned. For QnA, passing the associated recognizer into the dialog allows user input to be matched in the QnA knowledge base, subsequently, returning the matched response.

```js
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.set('storage', new builder.MemoryBotStorage());

var luisAppId = process.env.LuisAppId;
var luisAPIKey = process.env.LuisAPIKey;
var luisAPIHostName = process.env.LuisAPIHostName  // 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';

const LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey;

var luisRecognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);

var qnarecognizer = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
    authKey: process.env.QnAAuthKey,
    endpointHostName: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
});

var basicQnAMakerDialog = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
    recognizers: [qnarecognizer],
    defaultMessage: 'No match! Try changing the query terms!',
    qnaThreshold: 0.3
});

bot.recognizer(luisRecognizer);

bot.dialog('/', basicQnAMakerDialog);

bot.dialog('GreetingDialog',[
    (session) => {
        session.send('You reached the Greeting intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "What is your name?");
    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.userData.name = results.response;
        session.send("Glad you could make it, " + session.userData.name);
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Ask me something!");
    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.conversationData.question = results.response;
        session.send(session.conversationData.question + " is an interesting topic!")
        session.endDialog();
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Greeting'
})

bot.dialog('HelpDialog',
    (session) => {
        session.send('You reached the Help intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
        session.endDialog();
    }
).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Help'
})
```

You should be aware that the v3 SDKs will be losing their support come December, 2019. At that time, no new v3 bots will be available via Azure. I would recommend you consider building your bot using the newer [v4 SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/botframework-sdk). You can read more about it the v4 implementation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Hope of help!